# PowerBuilder 12 how to determine encoding of input file

Tags: encoding, powerbuilder

I'm new to PowerBuilder 12, and would like to know is there any way to determine the encoding (e.g. Unicode, BIG5) of an input file. Any comments and code samples are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PB 12.5 help file :

FileEncoding ( filename )

filename : The name of the file you want to test for encoding type

Return Values
EncodingANSI!
EncodingUTF8!
EncodingUTF16LE!
EncodingUTF16BE!
If filename does not exist, returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Finding Unicode is pretty easy, if you assume the Unicode file has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bom) prefix (although reality is that not all Unicode files do have this). Some code to do this is below. However, I have no idea about Big5; it looks to me (at first glance at the spec, never had occasion to use it) like it doesn't have a similar prefix.

Good luck,

Terry

```
function of_filetype (string as_filename) returns encoding

integer li_NullCount, li_NonNullCount, li_OffsetTest
long ll_File
encoding le_Return
blob lblb_UTF16BE, lblb_UTF16LE, lblb_UTF8, lblb_Test, lblb_BOMTest, lblb_Null

lblb_UTF16BE = Blob ("~hFE~hFF", EncodingANSI!)
lblb_UTF16LE = Blob ("~hFF~hFE", EncodingANSI!)
lblb_UTF8 = Blob ("~hEF~hBB~hBF", EncodingANSI!)
lblb_Null = blobmid (blob ("~h01", encodingutf16le!), 2, 1)

SetNull (le_Return)

// Get a set of bytes to test
ll_File = FileOpen (as_FileName, StreamMode!, Read!, Shared!)
FileRead (ll_File, lblb_Test)
FileClose (ll_File)

// test for BOMs: UTF-16BE (FF FE), UTF-16LE (FF FE), UTF-8 (EF BB BF)
lblb_BOMTest = BlobMid (lblb_Test, 1, Len (lblb_UTF16BE))
IF lblb_BOMTest = lblb_UTF16BE THEN RETURN EncodingUTF16BE!

lblb_BOMTest = BlobMid (lblb_Test, 1, Len (lblb_UTF16LE))
IF lblb_BOMTest = lblb_UTF16LE THEN RETURN EncodingUTF16LE!

lblb_BOMTest = BlobMid (lblb_Test, 1, Len (lblb_UTF8))
IF lblb_BOMTest = lblb_UTF8 THEN RETURN EncodingUTF8!

//I've removed a hack from here that I wouldn't encourage others to use, basically checking for 
//0x00 in places I'd "expect" them to be if it was a Unicode file, but that makes assumptions

RETURN le_Return
```

Comment: Thanks Terry! I will try that out.